# Detener gif en el login

Tags: javascript

he hecho un login y hice que al dar al boton de ingresar mostrara un gif de loading.. y lo muestra pero si en dado caso no son las credenciales correctas sigue el gif, o sea no se como pararlo, la idea es poner algo asi como un if para que diga que si da error, el gif se detenga, como se implementaria eso?

```
function loading(){
imagen = '<img src="./img/loading.gif"/>';


 document.getElementById('loading2').innerHTML = imagen;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te ha dicho el compañero la mejor forma de hacerlo es ocultándolo y mostrándolo según te convenga. Sería algo así:

#### HTML

```
...
<img id="loading" src="./img/loading.gif"/>
...
```

#### Javascript

```
function login(){
    loading(true);
    if(loginFails) loading(false);
}

function loading(boolean){
    if(boolean) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: La primera funcion si es login? o es loading igual me sale en consola que loading() no es una funcion y desde que corro el programa ya esta ejecutandose el login y no puedo detenerlo

Comment: ` <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick='loading()' id="signInBtn">Entrar</button>`

Answer (score 0):

si no te quieres complicar, la forma más sencilla sería incluir el gif en tu HTML, añadiendo un "display:none;" cuando haga clic para iniciar sesión habilitas el display, y cuando termines con todas las comprobaciones, (sean credenciales válidas o no), vuelves a ocultar el gif.

Un saludo.